# Error 1004 during Installation of OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, install

I was given a Mac by someone in my family, and wanted to restore to defaults (I already backed up). I found how to do this from countless webpages. It said to go into the recovery mode, erase the hard drive, and then reinstall the OS.

I followed these instructions, but during re-installation was given error 1004 repeatedly even after restarting and trying again. I am trying to install OS X Yosemite (newest version possible for this Mac). I can't even use my computer anymore because I can't re install OS X.

Anyone know what to do? I tried restoring from backup, but that says I don't have the space. If no one can figure re installing out, does anyone know how to restore if I don't have the space, and how do I get the space?

Comment: What Mac model is it?  Specs?

Comment: How do I figure that out? Remember, I'm stuck in recovery mode. Besides that, I am running OS X Yosemite with 150 GB space 2GB RAM.

Comment: Oh... and it is a Macbook Pro and is the thick kind of mac if that helps

Comment: See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201608  If you can get into recovery, you can click on the Apple Logo.  You can also turn it over and [Look it up by Serial Number](http://www.everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/)

Comment: Apple Logo in recovery doesn't include "About this Mac". It only shows "restart" or "shut down"

Comment: Can you open the Terminal? If so, running `sysctl hw.model` should give you the model identifier. In addition to that, `diskutil list` should give you a rudimentary overview over your drive(s), partition(s) and their size(s) (in case there is something weird that's eating up space or so).